# How reverse animation css in js?

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I have problem, I wanted reverse animation in JS, before the "animationToggler" class is deleted, I tried to add the code that is commented out, but this not working.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/jarek-babiak/pen/wvyEdyG)

```js
const menuToggler = document.querySelector('.toggler .hamburger');
menuToggler.addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.classList.toggle('animationToggler');
  // if(this.classList.contains('animationToggler')){
  //     this.style.animationDirection = "reverse"
  // }
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.classList.toggle('active');
  }, 400)
});
```

```css
.toggler {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.animationToggler {
  animation: animationTogglerMenu .8s ease;
}

.toggler p {
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.65rem;
  margin: 0 0 0 10px;
}

.hamburger .line {
  height: 4px;
  width: 2.5em;
  background: #000;
  margin: .45em 0;
  border-radius: 50px;
  transition: .6s;
}

.active .one {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(15px);
}

.active .two {
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: none;
}

.active .three {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(-15px);
}

@keyframes animationTogglerMenu {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(720deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="toggler">
  <div class="hamburger">
    <div class="line one"></div>
    <div class="line two"></div>
    <div class="line three"></div>
  </div>
  <p>Menu</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I've created a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) for you, feel free to edit if anything is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it myself, this is code in the JS

```
const menuToggler = document.querySelector('.toggler');
const menuTogglerHamburger = document.querySelector('.toggler .hamburger');

menuToggler.addEventListener('click', function(){

    //checking if there is a class animationToggler 
    if(menuTogglerHamburger.classList.contains('animationToggler')){
        //restart animation rotate
        menuTogglerHamburger.classList.remove('animationToggler');
        void menuTogglerHamburger.offsetWidth;
        menuTogglerHamburger.classList.add('animationToggler');

    }
    
    menuTogglerHamburger.classList.add('animationToggler');
    setTimeout(()=>{
        //animation line on the cross
        menuTogglerHamburger.classList.toggle('active');
    }, 200)
});
```